Lower bound on the Lévy-Prokhorov metric for normal distributions
Let $\mathfrak M(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the metric space of probability measures (over $\mathbb R^n)$ equipped with the Lévy-Prokhorov metric $\rho$. Consider two $n$-variate normal distributions $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_2)$ in $\mathfrak M(\mathbb R^n)$. I am interest in the difference $\rho\big(\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_1),\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_2)\big)$. In particular, I am interested in a lower bound of $\rho\big(\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_1),\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_2)\big)$. Certainly, $0$ is a lower bound, but this bound is not useful. Since the difference between $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ is responsible for any difference in $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_2)$, I am looking for a lower bound in terms of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$.
Are there any references for this problem?
A (small) caveat is that $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ may not be of full rank, i.e., there is no density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$.
Edit: Bogachev, Theorem 8.10.43, states that $$\Vert \mathcal N(0, \Sigma_1) - \mathcal N(0, \Sigma_2)\Vert_{BL} \leq 3\rho\big(\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_1),\mathcal N(0,\Sigma_2)\big),$$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{BL}$ is the bounded Lipschitz metric: $$\Vert Q\Vert_{BL} = \sup_{f\in BL}\left\vert\int f\operatorname dQ\right\vert$$ with $BL$ denoting the set of Lipschitz continuous functions $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that i) have Lipschitz constant $1$, and ii) are uniformly bounded by $1$.
So if I can find I can find such a uniformly bounded Lipschitz continuous functions $f$ that, when integrated with respect to the probability measure of a multivariate normal distribution evaluates to the variance-covariance matrix or a function of it, I would (probably) obtain what I want. I immediately thought about $f(x) = \Vert x\Vert_2^2$. However, this function is neigher uniformly bounded nor Lipschitz.

$\newcommand\Si\Sigma\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$Take any positive-definite symmetric matrix $B$.

Lemma 1: Let
\begin{equation}
    f_B:=a_B h_B,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    a_B:=\min\Big(1,\sqrt{\frac e{\|B\|}}\,\Big),
\end{equation}
$\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm, and
\begin{equation}
    h_B(x):=e^{-x^\top Bx/2}
\end{equation}
for $x\in\R^n$.
Then the function $f_B$ is $1$-Lipschitz and uniformly bounded by $1$.

This lemma will be proved at the end of this answer.
At this point, note that, for any $n\times n$ positive-definite symmetric matrix $\Si$,
\begin{equation}
\int f_B\,dN(0,\Si)
=\frac{a_B}{\sqrt{\det\Si\,\det(\Si^{-1}+B)}}
=\frac{a_B}{\sqrt{\det(I_n+\Si B)}}
=:g_B(\Si), 
\end{equation}
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
The equality
\begin{equation}
\int f_B\,dN(0,\Si)=g_B(\Si)    \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}
holds even when $\Si$ is not full rank. Indeed, if $\Si$ is any $n\times n$ positive-semidefinite symmetric matrix, then, by what has been shown, \eqref{10} holds with $\Si$ replaced by $\Si+hI_n$, for any real $h>0$. Now let $h\downarrow0$ and note that both sides of \eqref{10} are continuous wrt to $\Si$.
So, we get the lower bound
$$L_B(\Si_1,\Si_2):=|g_B(\Si_1)-g_B(\Si_2)|/3$$
on $\rho(N(0,\Si_1),N(0,\Si_2))$.
Given particular $\Si_1$ and $\Si_2$, the lower bound $L_B(\Si_1,\Si_2)$ can be maximized, at least numerically, wrt $B$.

More generally, instead of $f_B$, one can use any convex combinations of functions of the form $cf_B$ with $c\in[-1,1]$.

Proof of Lemma 1: That $f_B$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ is obvious.
Next, $\nabla h_B(0)=0$ and, for all $x\in\R^n$, letting $v:=B^{1/2}x$ and using the inequality $e^{-t}\le\frac1e\frac1t$ for real $t>0$, we get
\begin{equation}
    |\nabla h_B(x)|^2=e^{-x^\top Bx}\,|Bx|^2
    \le\frac1e\,\frac{x^\top B^2x}{x^\top Bx}
    =\frac1e\,\frac{v^\top Bv}{v^\top v}\le\frac{\|B\|}e.  
\end{equation}
So, $h_B$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\|B\|}e}$-Lipschitz and hence $f_B$ is $1$-Lipschitz. $\quad\Box$

Thank you for your reply. The problem is that at least one $\Sigma_i$ is not of full rank, i.e., I don't have a density (at least in the usual sense). It seems like your suggestion only works if both $\Sigma_i$s are of full rank, or am I missing something here?

@SydAmerikaner : The now simplified expression for $g_b(\Sigma)$ holds even if  $\Sigma$ is not of full rank.

If $\Sigma$ has full rank,$$\int f,\mathrm d\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)=\int a_b\exp\left(- x'(b I_n)x\right)\cdot(2\pi)^{-\frac n2}\det(\Sigma)^{-\frac12}\exp\left(-\frac 12 x'\Sigma^{-1}x\right),\mathrm dx = a_b(2\pi)^{-\frac n2}\det(\Sigma)^{-\frac12}\int\exp\left(-\frac12 x'(\Sigma^{-1}+bI_n)x\right),\mathrm dx = \frac{a_b(2\pi)^{\frac n2}}{(2\pi)^{\frac n2}\sqrt{\det(\Sigma)\det(\Sigma^{-1} + bI_n)}} = \frac{a_b}{\sqrt{\det(I_n+b\Sigma)}}$$ where does the $b$ in the numerator come from? And can you elaborate a bit on the continuity argument? I am afraid I don't understand. Thank you very much

@SydAmerikaner : The factor $b$ was indeed extraneous. However, I have now described in complete detail the more general function $f_B$. In particular, the continuity argument for the case when $\Sigma$ is not of full rank is now detailed.

Thank you very much. The expanded answer clarifies all my questions

@SydAmerikaner : I am glad this was of help.
